# Qual a diferença entre os adjetivos «monopolista» e «monopolístico»?

Tags: significado, adjetivos

Existe nomeadamente alguma situação em que um adjetivo seja apropriado e o outro não? No Aulete digital vem:

> [**Monopolista**](http://www.aulete.com.br/monopolista) a2g **1.** Que diz respeito a monopolismo. **2.** Diz-se de empresa ou pessoa que exerce monopólio.
>
> [**Monopolístico**](http://www.aulete.com.br/monopol%C3%ADstico) a **1.** Ref[erente] a monopólio, monopolismo e monopolista.

Não é óbvio qual seja a diferença. O dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa nem inclui *monopolístico*. Inclui outros pares semelhantes, como *futurista* e *futurístico*, mas também aí não é claro que haja diferença.

Então existe mesmo alguma diferença de significado? Apenas uma tendência para usar uma forma mais em certas situações e a outra forma noutras? Ou o que é? Não sei a diferença é a mesma para todos os pares de adjetivos *-ista* versus *-ístico*, mas se alguém tiver algo interessante a dizer acerca disso, eu gostaria de ler.

Comment: Se vai ver em inglês, (ou espanhol) monopolista é um subsantivo (noun) e monopolístico um adjetivo.

Comment: Sou economista, e não tenho essa ideia. Só para clarificar, *monopolista* é também substantivo, e.g. «um monopolista vende em dois mercados». A pergunta é sobre os adjetivos. *Um mercado monopolista* bate *um mercado monopolístico* 92 contra 21 no google books, e 4350 contra 360 no google search geral, o que parece confirmar a minha ideia e não a tua. (Tens que procurar *um mercado* ou *o mercado*, caso contrário o google não distingue português do espanhol.)

Comment: Certo, eu arranjei a pergunta. Não foi uma boa resposta mas já editei. Se procurar em outras línguas vê-se que monopolista não é adjetivo se não substantivo.

Comment: Para mim, a diferença é que un mercado *monopolista* tem monopolio nele e ponto, e uma pessoa *monopolista* é proponente deste sistema.  Um mercado *monopolístico* tem as cualidades de ser *monopólio* (sem haver de ser —ou não ser— *monopólio*).  Uma pessoa *monopolística* teria de ter essas qualidades *monopolistas* que acho possível mas improvável haha.  Mas fundamento esse entendimento por outras línguas que falo, parece-te o mesmo no português?

Comment: @guifa Nunca pensei nesse conceito, ter as qualidades para ser monopólio sem o ser de facto. Eu acho que só usei *monopolístico* em *concorrência monopolística*, provavelmente por influência do inglês. Mas já ouvi um colega a defender que se deveria dizer *empresa monopolística* e não *empresa monopolista*.

Comment: Isto não será como a diferença entre "consultoria" e a "consultadoria"?

Comment: @ANeves Ou seja, nenhuma?

Comment: Não ocorre «monopolístico» no Dicionário Houaiss da Língua Portuguesa, primeira edição.

Comment: @Pedro, ah, eu ainda não tinha o Houaiss quando escrevi esta pergunta. No dicionário da Academia também não. Mas eu já vi a palavra usada muitas vezes, e vem noutros dicionários.

Answer (score 1):

Quando leio adjetivos sufixados com 'ístico(a)', apreendo que o adjetivado não tem toda a essência do adjetivo, porém possui apenas caráter dele. Isto é, um "Lorem Ipsumístico", é um Lorem com aspectos, características, caráter próprio de Ipsum, porém não se define fundamental e completamente por ele.

Quanto ao "ista", pressuponho que trata-se daquele que, embora não necessariamente em integridade, é próprio do adjetivo em principalidade, ou que é o único adjetivo que importa em dado contexto. E.g., "o homem empirista", o homem certamente não possui apenas o empirismo em sua vida — provavelmente tem opinião política, profissão, hobbies —, porém no contexto de epistemologia, o fato de ele ser ateísta, ambientalista, ou o que seja, não importaria normalmente; e também não se trata de o homem ser meio empirista, ou incorporar aspectos empiristas, ele ***é*** empirista.

Monopolista, como adjetivo, seria algo que sobretudo pratica o ato de fazer monopólio, ao passo que monopolístico seria um que adota elementos dignos de associação à prática do monopólio.

Bem como pode ser estabelicido um paralelo com o inglês, 'Yeah, he is punk-ish", "Ele é meio punk-ístico" (alguém que se relaciona com o movimento punk).

Etimologicamente, o prefixo 'ístico' é a combinação dos gregos -ιστής e -ικός (-ista e -ico(a)); enquanto que o 'ista' provém do supracitado.

Alguns vocábulos entretanto, formam adjetivos com denotação equivalente com ambos os sufixos. A exemplo: 'holismo' sintetiza tanto 'holista' quanto 'holística', os quais denotam o mesmo.

[Sobre ambos os sufixos.](http://www.usp.br/gmhp/publ/AreA15.pdf)